# Where to store SQL creation script(s) in an android application?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android application and I need to embed a SQL script for the creation of its database.

Where is the best place to store that script ? 
What are the good practises related to this matter ?

I can see two potential candidates :

- The res folder
- Into a String directly in the class that will return the DB object

I am pretty much against using a String because of the clutter it adds to the code.

Comment: Normally, it's hardcoded into the DBHelper class.

Comment: Or, you could package your starting database with the app, [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), and skip the script entirely.

Comment: I personally find the way Ribot are doing it to be very clean https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/co/ribot/androidboilerplate/data/local/Db.java

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends to do this is by subclassing the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Have a look [at this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) to get you started.